# Requesting Alternate Ph.D. Interview Date

Tags: application

Good afternoon all,

I am currently experiencing a (good) dilemma of having to choose between two schools who have their interview date scheduled for the same day. At first, I was contemplating just asking for a phone/skype interview, but I am now thinking (after reading some threads here) of requesting an alternate interview date. How do I do this while staying professional and committed? Also, any feedback on how to respond if they say no?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your country, because this will depend on the country.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, United States

Comment: I don’t have direct experience with this, so I’ll leave t to someone else to answer. However, I would recommend that you ask *both* schools to reschedule. If you let one keep their original date and ask the roger to reschedule and you ask the one with the tighter schedule, that could e a problem. If instead you ask both and one is easily rescheduled you can always tell the other that the other school rescheduled and so you can make the original date.